# Error: [ng:areq] Angular when Ajax request to get data from php

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

I am trying make an ajax request to php from angular js. But I am not getting the data I have sent by php file.

I'm getting this error:
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=recordsCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

My source:

File app.js:

```
 (function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'contentsCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'views/contents.php'
                })

                .when('/jalse/:jalseId', {
                    controller: 'recordsCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'views/jalse.php'
                })



                .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    });

}());
```

File view.html:

```
<div class="content-panel">
    <div class="content-panel-title">
        <a href="#/records/" class="left"></a>
        <h2>  {{jalse.contentDate }}</h2>
    </div>

<div ng-repeat="jalse in records">
                {{jalse.contentDate }}
    </div>
```

File jalseFactory.js:

```
    (function () {

    'use strict';

    var jasleFactory = function ($http, $q) {

        var factory = {};

        factory.getJalses = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'includes/records.php'}).
                    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    }).
                    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        deferred.reject(data);
                    });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
        return factory;
    };

    jasleFactory.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
    angular.module('myApp').factory('jasleFactory', jasleFactory);

}());
```

File recordsCtrl.js:

```
 (function () {
    'use strict';

    var recordsCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        var jalseId = $routeParams.jalseId;

        $scope.records = jasleFactory.getJalse();

        $scope.jalse = null;

        function init() {
            for (var i = 0, len = $scope.records.length; i < len; i++) {
                if ($scope.records[i].contentID == parseInt(jalseId)) {
                    $scope.jalse = $scope.records[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        init();

    };

}());
```

Comment: You need to define your controller like `app.controller('recordsCtrl', recordsCtrl);`

Comment: thankful. I added this code:  
recordsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope' , '$routeParams' , 'jasleFactory'];
angular.module('myApp').controller('recordsCtrl', recordsCtrl); 
and change "var recordsCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams , jasleFactory)"
solved last error But Error: 
Error: jasleFactory.getJalse is not a function

Comment: solved last error But Error: jasleFactory.getJalse But :Error: input is undefined